# For loops with a dataframe in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I got a dataframe (`merged_df`) with 52 columns (I show here only the first 4):

```
   Row.names node_demand Node 1 Node 2
1     Node 1           3      0     87
2    Node 10           6     58     52
3    Node 11          10     43     70
4    Node 12          18     94      8
5    Node 13           3     44     63
6    Node 14           6     21     98
7    Node 15          20     31     64
8    Node 16           4     35     76
9    Node 17          14     58     52
10   Node 18          11     19     71
11   Node 19          19     62     38
12    Node 2          14     87      0
13   Node 20          15    102     19
14   Node 21          15     16     76
15   Node 22           4     54     51
16   Node 23          13     59     75
17   Node 24          13     73     28
18   Node 25           5     82     33
19   Node 26          16     62     72
20   Node 27           3     59     30
21   Node 28           7     73     32
22   Node 29          14     45     48
23    Node 3           1     43     78
24   Node 30          17     69     44
25   Node 31           3     70     43
26   Node 32           3     15     87
27   Node 33          12     38     72
28   Node 34          14     62     81
29   Node 35          20    104     17
30   Node 36          13     18     77
31   Node 37          10     70     22
32   Node 38           9     65     46
33   Node 39           6     24     64
34    Node 4          14     68     23
35   Node 40          18     85      8
36   Node 41           7     20     95
37   Node 42          20     55     82
38   Node 43           9     94     16
39   Node 44           1     10     79
40   Node 45           8     62     63
41   Node 46           5     50     88
42   Node 47           1     70     50
43   Node 48           7     54     73
44   Node 49           9     52     43
45    Node 5          19     57     48
46   Node 50           2      4     86
47    Node 6           2     76     22
48    Node 7          14     79     60
49    Node 8           6    108     25
50    Node 9           7    101     18
```

The columns `Node 1, Node 2 .....Node 45....Node 46` show the distance from the Node indicated on the column respect all the other nodes.

I want to pick the closest nodes, and then to select all the nodes under which `cumsum()` `node_demand` is less than 120, starting from the first row. Since the first value is the distance between the main Node and itself I don't consider the first row.

To do that for Node 1 I would do:

```
test <- merged_df[,c(1,2,3)] # Columns 1 and 2 are fixed
test <- test[(order(test[3])),][2:50,] # to get the closest distances first
test<- test[cumsum(test$node_demand)< 120,]
```

I then need to create a new variable for each node with the last value of the `cumsum()`

```
node_1 <- tail(cumsum(test$`Node 1`), n=1) # 381
```

The output for `node_1` would be `381`

To do the same for `node_2`:

```
test <- merged_df[,c(1,2,4)] #c(1,2,**4**) 4 instead of 3 as before
test <- test[(order(test[3])),][2:50,]
test<- test[cumsum(test$node_demand)< 120,]
node_2 <- tail(cumsum(test$`Node 2`), n=1)
```

The output for `node_2` is `178`

Since this process is very repetitive I guess a loop could do it but I am not sure how to create the different variables I need

```
for(i in 3:52){
  test <- merged_df[,c(1,2,i)]
  test <- merged_df[order(test[3]),][2:50]
  test<- test[cumsum(test$node_demand)< 120,]
}

node_1 <- tail(cumsum(test$test$`Node 1`), n=1) # should return 381

#I'm not sure how to create the variables node_1, node_2....node_50
```

The process to follow would be:

1. Create a subset of the dataframe using columns 1, 2 and i (representing the number from Node 1 to Node 50.
2. Sort the subset by the column `Node i` so the smallest distances are placed first.
3. I need to select rows until cumsum(node_demand) < 120. (which is what I do using `test<- test[cumsum(test$node_demand)< 120,]`)
4. Then I need to calculate cumsum(test$`Node 1`). This will give me the cumulative distance from all the nodes under the condition of cumsum(node_demand) < 120

Anybody could give me a hand?

Many thanks!

The output of dput() is :

```
structure(list(Row.names = structure(c("Node 1", "Node 10", "Node 11", 
"Node 12", "Node 13", "Node 14", "Node 15", "Node 16", "Node 17", 
"Node 18", "Node 19", "Node 2", "Node 20", "Node 21", "Node 22", 
"Node 23", "Node 24", "Node 25", "Node 26", "Node 27", "Node 28", 
"Node 29", "Node 3", "Node 30", "Node 31", "Node 32", "Node 33", 
"Node 34", "Node 35", "Node 36", "Node 37", "Node 38", "Node 39", 
"Node 4", "Node 40", "Node 41", "Node 42", "Node 43", "Node 44", 
"Node 45", "Node 46", "Node 47", "Node 48", "Node 49", "Node 5", 
"Node 50", "Node 6", "Node 7", "Node 8", "Node 9"), class = "AsIs"), 
    node_demand = c(3L, 6L, 10L, 18L, 3L, 6L, 20L, 4L, 14L, 11L, 
    19L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 4L, 13L, 13L, 5L, 16L, 3L, 7L, 14L, 1L, 
    17L, 3L, 3L, 12L, 14L, 20L, 13L, 10L, 9L, 6L, 14L, 18L, 7L, 
    20L, 9L, 1L, 8L, 5L, 1L, 7L, 9L, 19L, 2L, 2L, 14L, 6L, 7L
    ), `Node 1` = c(0, 58, 43, 94, 44, 21, 31, 35, 58, 19, 62, 
    87, 102, 16, 54, 59, 73, 82, 62, 59, 73, 45, 43, 69, 70, 
    15, 38, 62, 104, 18, 70, 65, 24, 68, 85, 20, 55, 94, 10, 
    62, 50, 70, 54, 52, 57, 4, 76, 79, 108, 101), `Node 2` = c(87, 
    52, 70, 8, 63, 98, 64, 76, 52, 71, 38, 0, 19, 76, 51, 75, 
    28, 33, 72, 30, 32, 48, 78, 44, 43, 87, 72, 81, 17, 77, 22, 
    46, 64, 23, 8, 95, 82, 16, 79, 63, 88, 50, 73, 43, 48, 86, 
    22, 60, 25, 18), `Node 3` = c(43, 28, 11, 84, 15, 35, 52, 
    68, 30, 45, 73, 78, 97, 43, 72, 20, 78, 57, 91, 58, 80, 58, 
    0, 42, 83, 29, 69, 94, 91, 51, 70, 36, 41, 70, 79, 33, 22, 
    78, 34, 25, 13, 86, 84, 35, 73, 46, 60, 43, 101, 94), `Node 4` = c(68, 
    50, 62, 30, 56, 82, 43, 53, 49, 51, 16, 23, 34, 57, 29, 71, 
    10, 44, 50, 15, 15, 26, 70, 46, 25, 71, 49, 58, 39, 57, 5, 
    47, 45, 0, 19, 79, 76, 37, 62, 61, 81, 31, 50, 36, 25, 67, 
    30, 65, 41, 35), `Node 5` = c(57, 62, 66, 54, 62, 74, 30, 
    33, 61, 39, 10, 48, 55, 45, 15, 79, 23, 66, 26, 30, 24, 16, 
    73, 62, 22, 64, 27, 34, 63, 42, 28, 62, 37, 25, 42, 71, 80, 
    62, 55, 73, 84, 24, 28, 48, 0, 55, 53, 81, 63, 58), `Node 6` = c(76, 
    34, 54, 27, 46, 84, 60, 73, 36, 63, 45, 22, 40, 68, 53, 58, 
    38, 16, 77, 25, 41, 46, 60, 29, 50, 73, 71, 85, 34, 71, 28, 
    29, 55, 30, 27, 82, 67, 20, 67, 44, 70, 56, 75, 28, 53, 76, 
    0, 44, 41, 35), `Node 7` = c(79, 24, 38, 62, 36, 75, 72, 
    93, 23, 72, 75, 60, 79, 72, 84, 28, 75, 30, 105, 58, 79, 
    69, 43, 20, 88, 69, 91, 112, 66, 80, 66, 20, 66, 65, 64, 
    73, 38, 53, 70, 18, 45, 93, 102, 35, 81, 82, 44, 0, 81, 75
    ), `Node 8` = c(108, 75, 94, 23, 86, 120, 85, 91, 76, 91, 
    54, 25, 11, 97, 64, 98, 40, 52, 83, 49, 41, 67, 101, 67, 
    51, 109, 88, 91, 21, 98, 39, 69, 84, 41, 27, 117, 106, 28, 
    101, 85, 111, 56, 85, 66, 63, 107, 41, 81, 0, 7), `Node 9` = c(101, 
    68, 87, 17, 79, 113, 78, 86, 69, 85, 48, 18, 9, 90, 58, 91, 
    35, 46, 78, 42, 36, 60, 94, 60, 47, 102, 83, 87, 18, 91, 
    32, 62, 78, 35, 20, 110, 99, 23, 94, 79, 104, 52, 80, 59, 
    58, 100, 35, 75, 7, 0), `Node 10` = c(58, 0, 23, 57, 16, 
    58, 51, 70, 8, 50, 58, 52, 71, 51, 63, 24, 60, 29, 85, 40, 
    62, 48, 28, 16, 69, 49, 69, 91, 64, 59, 50, 8, 43, 50, 55, 
    56, 34, 50, 48, 12, 37, 73, 80, 14, 62, 60, 34, 24, 75, 68
    ), `Node 11` = c(43, 23, 0, 76, 10, 37, 45, 65, 22, 41, 65, 
    70, 89, 39, 67, 17, 71, 52, 85, 51, 73, 51, 11, 34, 77, 31, 
    64, 89, 83, 47, 63, 30, 36, 62, 71, 35, 18, 72, 34, 21, 19, 
    81, 79, 27, 66, 46, 54, 38, 94, 87), `Node 12` = c(94, 57, 
    76, 0, 69, 104, 71, 83, 56, 78, 44, 8, 17, 83, 58, 79, 34, 
    36, 78, 38, 38, 55, 84, 47, 50, 94, 79, 87, 9, 85, 29, 50, 
    71, 30, 12, 101, 86, 14, 87, 67, 93, 56, 80, 49, 54, 94, 
    27, 62, 23, 17), `Node 13` = c(44, 16, 10, 69, 0, 43, 45, 
    63, 18, 40, 60, 63, 82, 40, 61, 22, 65, 44, 82, 44, 67, 47, 
    15, 30, 71, 34, 62, 86, 77, 48, 56, 24, 34, 56, 65, 41, 27, 
    64, 34, 19, 26, 74, 76, 21, 62, 47, 46, 36, 86, 79), `Node 14` = c(21, 
    58, 37, 104, 43, 0, 46, 56, 58, 35, 78, 98, 114, 30, 73, 
    51, 88, 86, 82, 71, 89, 60, 35, 70, 88, 12, 58, 82, 113, 
    36, 84, 66, 39, 82, 97, 3, 44, 103, 22, 58, 37, 89, 74, 57, 
    74, 25, 84, 75, 120, 113), `Node 15` = c(31, 51, 45, 71, 
    45, 46, 0, 27, 49, 12, 35, 64, 77, 16, 34, 61, 47, 68, 42, 
    39, 49, 19, 52, 56, 48, 37, 22, 45, 80, 16, 46, 55, 16, 43, 
    60, 43, 58, 74, 29, 59, 61, 49, 38, 40, 30, 30, 60, 72, 85, 
    78), `Node 16` = c(35, 70, 65, 83, 63, 56, 27, 0, 70, 26, 
    42, 76, 85, 32, 28, 82, 53, 85, 29, 48, 51, 30, 68, 77, 44, 
    48, 9, 28, 93, 23, 55, 74, 29, 53, 72, 54, 80, 87, 38, 79, 
    79, 42, 19, 59, 33, 31, 73, 93, 91, 86), `Node 17` = c(58, 
    8, 22, 56, 18, 58, 49, 70, 0, 49, 56, 52, 71, 50, 63, 23, 
    59, 31, 84, 41, 63, 47, 30, 12, 70, 49, 68, 90, 63, 57, 50, 
    10, 43, 49, 54, 55, 31, 51, 48, 14, 37, 74, 80, 14, 61, 60, 
    36, 23, 76, 69), `Node 18` = c(19, 50, 41, 78, 40, 35, 12, 
    26, 49, 0, 44, 71, 85, 8, 39, 58, 55, 71, 48, 43, 56, 26, 
    45, 58, 54, 27, 25, 50, 87, 8, 53, 55, 9, 51, 68, 33, 55, 
    80, 17, 57, 55, 55, 41, 41, 39, 18, 63, 72, 91, 85), `Node 19` = c(62, 
    58, 65, 44, 60, 78, 35, 42, 56, 44, 0, 38, 46, 50, 19, 77, 
    14, 58, 35, 24, 18, 18, 73, 56, 21, 68, 37, 44, 53, 48, 19, 
    57, 40, 16, 32, 75, 79, 53, 58, 69, 84, 25, 37, 44, 10, 60, 
    45, 75, 54, 48), `Node 20` = c(102, 71, 89, 17, 82, 114, 
    77, 85, 71, 85, 46, 19, 0, 90, 58, 94, 33, 51, 75, 44, 35, 
    60, 97, 63, 46, 103, 81, 84, 18, 91, 32, 66, 78, 34, 19, 
    111, 101, 28, 95, 82, 107, 51, 78, 62, 55, 101, 40, 79, 11, 
    9), `Node 21` = c(16, 51, 39, 83, 40, 30, 16, 32, 50, 8, 
    50, 76, 90, 0, 46, 55, 62, 74, 54, 49, 63, 33, 43, 59, 61, 
    22, 30, 56, 92, 10, 59, 57, 15, 57, 73, 27, 51, 84, 16, 57, 
    51, 62, 48, 44, 45, 17, 68, 72, 97, 90), `Node 22` = c(54, 
    63, 67, 58, 61, 73, 34, 28, 63, 39, 19, 51, 58, 46, 0, 81, 
    26, 67, 26, 28, 23, 19, 72, 65, 16, 63, 26, 33, 67, 42, 29, 
    64, 35, 29, 46, 70, 83, 64, 52, 74, 84, 16, 23, 49, 15, 52, 
    53, 84, 64, 58), `Node 23` = c(59, 24, 17, 79, 22, 51, 61, 
    82, 23, 58, 77, 75, 94, 55, 81, 0, 81, 50, 100, 62, 84, 65, 
    20, 33, 90, 46, 80, 105, 85, 64, 73, 29, 53, 71, 77, 49, 
    13, 73, 51, 14, 19, 94, 95, 35, 79, 63, 58, 28, 98, 91), 
    `Node 24` = c(73, 60, 71, 34, 65, 88, 47, 53, 59, 55, 14, 
    28, 33, 62, 26, 81, 0, 53, 44, 22, 7, 29, 78, 56, 18, 77, 
    49, 53, 43, 60, 10, 57, 50, 10, 22, 85, 85, 43, 68, 71, 90, 
    24, 47, 46, 23, 71, 38, 75, 40, 35), `Node 25` = c(82, 29, 
    52, 36, 44, 86, 68, 85, 31, 71, 58, 33, 51, 74, 67, 50, 53, 
    0, 91, 39, 56, 58, 57, 22, 66, 76, 82, 99, 40, 79, 43, 22, 
    62, 44, 39, 84, 61, 25, 72, 36, 65, 72, 89, 30, 66, 83, 16, 
    30, 52, 46), `Node 26` = c(62, 85, 85, 78, 82, 82, 42, 29, 
    84, 48, 35, 72, 75, 54, 26, 100, 44, 91, 0, 53, 43, 37, 91, 
    86, 34, 74, 25, 9, 86, 46, 51, 86, 50, 50, 66, 80, 99, 86, 
    64, 95, 101, 30, 12, 71, 26, 59, 77, 105, 83, 78), `Node 27` = c(59, 
    40, 51, 38, 44, 71, 39, 48, 41, 43, 24, 30, 44, 49, 28, 62, 
    22, 39, 53, 0, 23, 23, 58, 40, 30, 60, 46, 60, 48, 50, 14, 
    39, 35, 15, 29, 69, 67, 39, 51, 52, 69, 34, 50, 27, 30, 58, 
    25, 58, 49, 42), `Node 28` = c(73, 62, 73, 38, 67, 89, 49, 
    51, 63, 56, 18, 32, 35, 63, 23, 84, 7, 56, 43, 23, 0, 31, 
    80, 60, 12, 78, 48, 51, 46, 61, 14, 60, 51, 15, 27, 86, 89, 
    46, 68, 74, 92, 18, 44, 49, 24, 71, 41, 79, 41, 36), `Node 29` = c(45, 
    48, 51, 55, 47, 60, 19, 30, 47, 26, 18, 48, 60, 33, 19, 65, 
    29, 58, 37, 23, 31, 0, 58, 50, 31, 50, 26, 43, 64, 31, 28, 
    50, 23, 26, 44, 57, 66, 59, 40, 59, 69, 33, 34, 35, 16, 43, 
    46, 69, 67, 60), `Node 30` = c(69, 16, 34, 47, 30, 70, 56, 
    77, 12, 58, 56, 44, 63, 59, 65, 33, 56, 22, 86, 40, 60, 50, 
    42, 0, 69, 61, 74, 93, 53, 66, 47, 9, 51, 46, 46, 67, 41, 
    41, 59, 21, 49, 74, 84, 19, 62, 70, 29, 20, 67, 60), `Node 31` = c(70, 
    69, 77, 50, 71, 88, 48, 44, 70, 54, 21, 43, 46, 61, 16, 90, 
    18, 66, 34, 30, 12, 31, 83, 69, 0, 77, 42, 42, 58, 58, 24, 
    68, 50, 25, 39, 86, 94, 57, 67, 81, 95, 6, 34, 55, 22, 68, 
    50, 88, 51, 47), `Node 32` = c(15, 49, 31, 94, 34, 12, 37, 
    48, 49, 27, 68, 87, 103, 22, 63, 46, 77, 76, 74, 60, 78, 
    50, 29, 61, 77, 0, 50, 75, 102, 29, 73, 57, 28, 71, 86, 9, 
    42, 92, 11, 51, 35, 78, 66, 47, 64, 19, 73, 69, 109, 102), 
    `Node 33` = c(38, 69, 64, 79, 62, 58, 22, 9, 68, 25, 37, 
    72, 81, 30, 26, 80, 49, 82, 25, 46, 48, 26, 69, 74, 42, 50, 
    0, 26, 88, 22, 51, 72, 28, 49, 67, 55, 79, 84, 40, 78, 79, 
    40, 18, 57, 27, 34, 71, 91, 88, 83), `Node 34` = c(62, 91, 
    89, 87, 86, 82, 45, 28, 90, 50, 44, 81, 84, 56, 33, 105, 
    53, 99, 9, 60, 51, 43, 94, 93, 42, 75, 26, 0, 96, 47, 60, 
    93, 53, 58, 75, 80, 103, 95, 65, 101, 104, 37, 12, 77, 34, 
    58, 85, 112, 91, 87), `Node 35` = c(104, 64, 83, 9, 77, 113, 
    80, 93, 63, 87, 53, 17, 18, 92, 67, 85, 43, 40, 86, 48, 46, 
    64, 91, 53, 58, 102, 88, 96, 0, 94, 38, 57, 80, 39, 21, 110, 
    93, 17, 96, 73, 100, 64, 89, 57, 63, 103, 34, 66, 21, 18), 
    `Node 36` = c(18, 59, 47, 85, 48, 36, 16, 23, 57, 8, 48, 
    77, 91, 10, 42, 64, 60, 79, 46, 50, 61, 31, 51, 66, 58, 29, 
    22, 47, 94, 0, 59, 64, 18, 57, 74, 34, 61, 87, 21, 65, 60, 
    57, 40, 49, 42, 16, 71, 80, 98, 91), `Node 37` = c(70, 50, 
    63, 29, 56, 84, 46, 55, 50, 53, 19, 22, 32, 59, 29, 73, 10, 
    43, 51, 14, 14, 28, 70, 47, 24, 73, 51, 60, 38, 59, 0, 48, 
    47, 5, 18, 81, 78, 35, 64, 62, 82, 30, 52, 37, 28, 69, 28, 
    66, 39, 32), `Node 38` = c(65, 8, 30, 50, 24, 66, 55, 74, 
    10, 55, 57, 46, 66, 57, 64, 29, 57, 22, 86, 39, 60, 50, 36, 
    9, 68, 57, 72, 93, 57, 64, 48, 0, 48, 47, 50, 63, 39, 44, 
    55, 16, 44, 73, 83, 16, 62, 66, 29, 20, 69, 62), `Node 39` = c(24, 
    43, 36, 71, 34, 39, 16, 29, 43, 9, 40, 64, 78, 15, 35, 53, 
    50, 62, 50, 35, 51, 23, 41, 51, 50, 28, 28, 53, 80, 18, 47, 
    48, 0, 45, 62, 36, 53, 72, 18, 51, 52, 51, 43, 33, 37, 23, 
    55, 66, 84, 78), `Node 40` = c(85, 55, 71, 12, 65, 97, 60, 
    72, 54, 68, 32, 8, 19, 73, 46, 77, 22, 39, 66, 29, 27, 44, 
    79, 46, 39, 86, 67, 75, 21, 74, 18, 50, 62, 19, 0, 94, 83, 
    23, 78, 66, 89, 45, 68, 44, 42, 84, 27, 64, 27, 20), `Node 41` = c(20, 
    56, 35, 101, 41, 3, 43, 54, 55, 33, 75, 95, 111, 27, 70, 
    49, 85, 84, 80, 69, 86, 57, 33, 67, 86, 9, 55, 80, 110, 34, 
    81, 63, 36, 79, 94, 0, 42, 100, 20, 56, 36, 86, 72, 55, 71, 
    24, 82, 73, 117, 110), `Node 42` = c(55, 34, 18, 86, 27, 
    44, 58, 80, 31, 55, 79, 82, 101, 51, 83, 13, 85, 61, 99, 
    67, 89, 66, 22, 41, 94, 42, 79, 103, 93, 61, 78, 39, 53, 
    76, 83, 42, 0, 82, 48, 26, 16, 97, 95, 42, 80, 59, 67, 38, 
    106, 99), `Node 43` = c(94, 50, 72, 14, 64, 103, 74, 87, 
    51, 80, 53, 16, 28, 84, 64, 73, 43, 25, 86, 39, 46, 59, 78, 
    41, 57, 92, 84, 95, 17, 87, 35, 44, 72, 37, 23, 100, 82, 
    0, 86, 59, 87, 63, 87, 45, 62, 94, 20, 53, 28, 23), `Node 44` = c(10, 
    48, 34, 87, 34, 22, 29, 38, 48, 17, 58, 79, 95, 16, 52, 51, 
    68, 72, 64, 51, 68, 40, 34, 59, 67, 11, 40, 65, 96, 21, 64, 
    55, 18, 62, 78, 20, 48, 86, 0, 52, 43, 67, 55, 43, 55, 13, 
    67, 70, 101, 94), `Node 45` = c(62, 12, 21, 67, 19, 58, 59, 
    79, 14, 57, 69, 63, 82, 57, 74, 14, 71, 36, 95, 52, 74, 59, 
    25, 21, 81, 51, 78, 101, 73, 65, 62, 16, 51, 61, 66, 56, 
    26, 59, 52, 0, 30, 85, 91, 26, 73, 65, 44, 18, 85, 79), `Node 46` = c(50, 
    37, 19, 93, 26, 37, 61, 79, 37, 55, 84, 88, 107, 51, 84, 
    19, 90, 65, 101, 69, 92, 69, 13, 49, 95, 35, 79, 104, 100, 
    60, 82, 44, 52, 81, 89, 36, 16, 87, 43, 30, 0, 98, 95, 45, 
    84, 54, 70, 45, 111, 104), `Node 47` = c(70, 73, 81, 56, 
    74, 89, 49, 42, 74, 55, 25, 50, 51, 62, 16, 94, 24, 72, 30, 
    34, 18, 33, 86, 74, 6, 78, 40, 37, 64, 57, 30, 73, 51, 31, 
    45, 86, 97, 63, 67, 85, 98, 0, 30, 60, 24, 67, 56, 93, 56, 
    52), `Node 48` = c(54, 80, 79, 80, 76, 74, 38, 19, 80, 41, 
    37, 73, 78, 48, 23, 95, 47, 89, 12, 50, 44, 34, 84, 84, 34, 
    66, 18, 12, 89, 40, 52, 83, 43, 50, 68, 72, 95, 87, 55, 91, 
    95, 30, 0, 67, 28, 50, 75, 102, 85, 80), `Node 49` = c(52, 
    14, 27, 49, 21, 57, 40, 59, 14, 41, 44, 43, 62, 44, 49, 35, 
    46, 30, 71, 27, 49, 35, 35, 19, 55, 47, 57, 77, 57, 49, 37, 
    16, 33, 36, 44, 55, 42, 45, 43, 26, 45, 60, 67, 0, 48, 53, 
    28, 35, 66, 59), `Node 50` = c(4, 60, 46, 94, 47, 25, 30, 
    31, 60, 18, 60, 86, 101, 17, 52, 63, 71, 83, 59, 58, 71, 
    43, 46, 70, 68, 19, 34, 58, 103, 16, 69, 66, 23, 67, 84, 
    24, 59, 94, 13, 65, 54, 67, 50, 53, 55, 0, 76, 82, 107, 100
    )), .Names = c("Row.names", "node_demand", "Node 1", "Node 2", 
"Node 3", "Node 4", "Node 5", "Node 6", "Node 7", "Node 8", "Node 9", 
"Node 10", "Node 11", "Node 12", "Node 13", "Node 14", "Node 15", 
"Node 16", "Node 17", "Node 18", "Node 19", "Node 20", "Node 21", 
"Node 22", "Node 23", "Node 24", "Node 25", "Node 26", "Node 27", 
"Node 28", "Node 29", "Node 30", "Node 31", "Node 32", "Node 33", 
"Node 34", "Node 35", "Node 36", "Node 37", "Node 38", "Node 39", 
"Node 40", "Node 41", "Node 42", "Node 43", "Node 44", "Node 45", 
"Node 46", "Node 47", "Node 48", "Node 49", "Node 50"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-50L))
```

Comment: PLease can you paste the output of `dput(merged_df)` in your question. And please add your expected output for the first two nodes. Not exactly clear what you want.

Comment: Sure thing, 'node_1' should return 114, I will explain in the main post what it means.

Comment: Can you also please share the expected output?

Comment: Done :).
The values of Column Node 1, Node 2 represent distances, basically I need to add up all the distances whilst the cumulative sum of node_demand is below 120 and assign the result to the a new variable called node_1, node_2 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
d %>% 
  as.tibble() %>% 
  gather(k,v, -node_demand, -Row.names) %>% 
  arrange(k, v) %>% 
  group_by(k) %>% 
  filter(Row.names != k) %>%  
  filter(cumsum(node_demand)<120) %>% 
  summarise(sum(v)) 
# A tibble: 50 x 2
   k       `sum(v)`
   <chr>      <dbl>
 1 Node 1       381
 2 Node 10      202
 3 Node 11      332
 4 Node 12      186
 5 Node 13      262
 6 Node 14      419
 7 Node 15      282
 8 Node 16      279
 9 Node 17      272
10 Node 18      302
# ... with 40 more rows
```

Prove result for Node 1 and 2:

```
.Last.value %>% 
  filter(k %in% c("Node 1", "Node 2"))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  k      `sum(v)`
  <chr>     <dbl>
1 Node 1      381
2 Node 2      178
```

The idea is to transform the data from long to wide. After arranging, we group by Node (`column k`) and filter 1) "self-nodes" and 2) `cumsum<120`. Finally calculate the sum for each Node.